# Airflow 1.10: sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound: No row was found for one()

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

When you follow this tutorial:

http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2017/03/19/developing-workflows-with-apache-airflow/

or when you create any DAG and try it to run using API by this script:

```sh
for i in {1..10}; do
    RUN_ID=BASH_REST_CALL__$(uuidgen)
    curl -X POST \
      http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/my_test_dag/dag_runs \
      -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
      -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d "{\"run_id\": \"${RUN_ID}\"}" &
 done
```

on some of responses you can see:

```
                          ____/ (  (    )   )  \___
                         /( (  (  )   _    ))  )   )\
                       ((     (   )(    )  )   (   )  )
                     ((/  ( _(   )   (   _) ) (  () )  )
                    ( (  ( (_)   ((    (   )  .((_ ) .  )_
                   ( (  )    (      (  )    )   ) . ) (   )
                  (  (   (  (   ) (  _  ( _) ).  ) . ) ) ( )
                  ( (  (   ) (  )   (  ))     ) _)(   )  )  )
                 ( (  ( \ ) (    (_  ( ) ( )  )   ) )  )) ( )
                  (  (   (  (   (_ ( ) ( _    )  ) (  )  )   )
                 ( (  ( (  (  )     (_  )  ) )  _)   ) _( ( )
                  ((  (   )(    (     _    )   _) _(_ (  (_ )
                   (_((__(_(__(( ( ( |  ) ) ) )_))__))_)___)
                   ((__)        \\||lll|l||///          \_))
                            (   /(/ (  )  ) )\   )
                          (    ( ( ( | | ) ) )\   )
                           (   /(| / ( )) ) ) )) )
                         (     ( ((((_(|)_)))))     )
                          (      ||\(|(|)|/||     )
                        (        |(||(||)||||        )
                          (     //|/l|||)|\\ \     )
                        (/ / //  /|//||||\\  \ \  \ _)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node: 5b104ab0dac5
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/api/auth/backend/default.py", line 32, in decorated
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/api/experimental/endpoints.py", line 78, in trigger_dag
    dr = trigger.trigger_dag(dag_id, run_id, conf, execution_date)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/api/common/experimental/trigger_dag.py", line 101, in trigger_dag
    replace_microseconds=replace_microseconds,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/api/common/experimental/trigger_dag.py", line 77, in _trigger_dag
    external_trigger=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 73, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 4382, in create_dagrun
    run.refresh_from_db()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 73, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line 5064, in refresh_from_db
    DR.run_id == self.run_id
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3046, in one
    raise orm_exc.NoResultFound("No row was found for one()")
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound: No row was found for one()
```

Answer (score 2):

I get the same error. I think it is due to inserting many tasks at the same time. For some reason it makes it blow up. It you add a sleep command in there it should work, but this is obviously not ideal since sometimes you *want* to insert multiple tasks at once.

I think this may also be due to timestamps being dealed with differently in mysql vs postgres. It seems that the airflow team mostly tests on postgres. I am updating now to use postgres instead of mysql. I will update then.

Comment: Using postgres I am able to submit a few jobs at once, but not more than 3 or 4.

Comment: Ok! I have finally hit the sweet spot! If I have a delay of 500ms between requests, it works! Anything less than that and it fails. Its still not ideal, but better than the having to wait 1 whole second like I was having to do with the mysql connector.